# Getting around access specifiers with C++0x decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, access-specifier

Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
private:
    class B {};
public:
    B f();
};

A a;

A::B g()
{
    return a.f();
}
```

The compiler rejects this - g cannot return A::B because A::B is private.

But suppose I now use decltype to specify the return value of g:

```
class A
{
private:
    class B {};
public:
    B f();
};

A a;

decltype(a.f()) g()
{
    return a.f();
}
```

All of a sudden it compiles fine (with g++ >= 4.4).

So I've basically used decltype to get around an access specifier in a way I would not have been able to in C++98.

Is this intentional? Is this good practice?

Comment: related: [delegating into private parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952216/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access only applies to *names* (and as a special case, to constructors/destructors). It doesn't apply to entities themselves. The spec further elaborates

> [ Note: because access control applies to names, if access control is applied to a typedef name, only the accessibility of the typedef name itself is considered. The accessibility of the entity referred to by the typedef is not considered. For example,
>
> ```
> class A {
>   class B { };
> public:
>   typedef B BB;
> };
>
> void f() {
>   A::BB x; // OK, typedef name A::BB is public
>   A::B y; // access error, A::B is private
> }
> ```
>
> — end note ]

So what you have disovered here isn't surprising. You can get hold of the type `A::B` even in C++03, when taking the address of `f` by saying `&A::f` and passing it to a function template deducing the return type.